# How to access a method from another class outside the creator of the instance

Tags: java

I created 3 java files:main.java, GUI.java, Serial.java

In Main I created instances of two last java files.
I can call methods from gui and serial from within Main.
I cannot call methods from the instances gui and serial outside Main.

```
package main;
 public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GUI gui = new GUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);

            Serial serial = new Serial();
            serial.getPorts();
            fillList();
        }

        public void fillList () {
            gui.setList("hoi");
        }
    }
```

Why is this? How can I call methods from gui from method fillList?
Thanks for any insights.

Comment: `gui` and `serial` are local variables, so they don't exist outside of the `main()` method.

Comment: I understand the why, thanks! Now the 'how' :-)

Comment: Use a class variable if you want it to live outside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances only exist within the method they're declared, in this case the constructor. A common way of getting around this is to declare a `field` in your class, and assign the value of that field in the constructor (or other method). Try:

```
package main;
public class Main {
    // private GUI gui; // replaced this line with the below. See comment 5
    private static GUI gui; // this is the new field declaration

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui = new GUI(); // note I removed the class declaration here since it was declared above.
        gui.setVisible(true);

        Serial serial = new Serial();
        serial.getPorts();
        fillList();
    }

    public void fillList () {
        gui.setList("hoi"); // now this method has access to the gui field 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion! So this 'field' gives me access to the variable in a class. Let's say I'd like to do a gui.JComboBox.addItem(text); I simply declare a field in my routine and have access to this object? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the field gives access to the variable to all methods in the class. Without knowing the internals of your `GUI` class, it looks as if `JComboBox` is a field on `GUI`, so as long as that field is declared to be `public`, the `gui` instance created in the `Main` constructor will have access to the `gui.JComboBox` field. Then, the `JComboBox` field in the `GUI` class appears to have a method called `addItem` (I can tell it's a method because you're calling it with parens). Again, if the `addItem` method is `public`, then the `JComboBox` and in turn the `gui` should have access to the method.

Comment: In other words, according to how the privacy settings are declared, the local `gui` field should have access to `JComboBox` (and in turn all its fields and methods) the same way it has access to `setList` on line 15. This is true for all `public` fields and methods declared in the `GUI` class.

Comment: I've tried your method (copy/pasted) but Netbeans shows an error at the lines 'gui = new GUI();' and the next. The error says "non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context". The GUI constructor is public, the init method is private. Is that the reason it shows the error?

Comment: Ah, I missed that your `main` method was `static`. The error is saying that the `gui` field is nonstatic, but we're trying to reference it from the `static` `main` method. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks! I think I'm getting the grasps of it! Now looking for a way to connect to this gui instance from other classes as well. Goal is to create a model-view-controller model. Not sure quite how to do that, but I think it has something to do with Inheritance. Looking into it rightnow. (thought proces: make Main a superclass, by extending GUI and Serial)...